# How to extract rows of the same value in 2D keras tensor?

Tags: deep-learning, keras

I am new to keras, recently work on a project which needs to extract rows of the same labels. Explained below:

k_tensor = [Batch, Labels]

where Batch is batch_size in deep learning training, labels could be thought as categories. I want to extract the labels of the same value.

how to get this in keras.    : )

Thanks

Comment: Could you expand on "I want to extract the labels of the same value"? I think providing an example would help.

Comment: for example , batch samples are: [[2, 2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3, 3], [4, 4, 4, 4]], totally three samples. Related labels(one hot are), [[1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0 , 0], [0, 0, 0, 1]], assuming there are four categories. I want to group [2, 2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3, 3], because they belong to the same catogory. How to achieve this in keras.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include any additional information you have to your question. Avoid adding this in the comments, as they are harder to read and can be deleted easier. The edit button for your post is just below the post's tags.